# Can I set the <recycling> options in my website's web.config file?

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a website that is deployed to our customers as part of an application install and wanted to know if I can set the `<recycling>` options for my application in the website's web.config file or can this only be done via the applicationHost.config file for IIS?